# Is there a fast way to parse html5 in php (something that rival libxml)

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument

I need to do some dom manipulation and I am having trouble finding the right tool.

Originally I was using libxml domDocument, but while its nice and fast it does not play well with HTML5.

I then tried "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), and found that while its very nice to use, it is far too slow for my needs.

So I am left looking for something that is close to the speed of using domDocument, but can handle HTML5 reliably.

Does such a wonderful creature exist? Or am I hunting for the impossible. If not, does anyone have a reliable workaround?

(I know others have asked about parsing HTML5, but I didn't see an existing question that commented on the issue of speed).

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I said in the question, I tried simplehtmldom, and while it is nice to use it is much slower.